# Putting outputs into github issues

Tags: github-issues

I often need to add a stacktrace to issue. Manually adding spaces to pasted lines is not comfortable. How to do this other way than manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surround code and other fixed-width content with three backticks in [GitHub Flavoured Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) like this:

````
```
stack trace here
```
````

The official name for it is called *code fencing*.

In addition, you can do syntax highlighting on code if necessary like this:

````
```js
console.log('This code will be highlighted properly on GitHub');
```
````